# How to create a path for saving the log file? And save in separate log file each time?

Tags: python, logging

now I need to save a log file but don't know how to save the log file to the desired path. How to make the line?

I have used this but there appears a bug. Please help! Thanks!

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='daily_report.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.config.fileConfig('C:/.../.../.../daily_report.log', disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

I have found my own solution to add directly the path into 'filename=...' of basicConfig.

The next problem is how to save the log file into a separate file with the datetime format on file'sname

Comment: Had you searched how to create folders?

Comment: you mean from os.makedir()? I'm new in create logging file and path. I have read on https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging.html but seem to not mention on the path to save file

Comment: Please include the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
logging.FileHandler("C:/.../.../.../daily_report.log")
```

after the `.basicConfig`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just replace directly to the first line code.

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename="C:/.../.../.../daily_report.log"), level=logging.INFO)
```

The next question is how to produce a separate file log for each time run the code?